# Запрос на изменение порядка в таблице местами

Tags: php, sql

В выводе таблицы языков, на определенном языке можно нажать стрелку вверх, и тем самым поменять их порядок местами

Есть переменная **$itemToUp** в которой хранится номер порядка языка который хотят переместить

Таблица язков выглядит так:

```
id   name           code listOrder
1    По-русски      ru   1
2    Eesti keeles   et   2
3    In English     en   3
```

Например, если я нажму на стрелку вверх у эстонского языка, то его listOrder 2 поменяется на тот что выше него, то есть на listOrder руссккого языка 1, а русский язык будет 2.

```
<?php
$itemToUp=$_POST['codeToUp']; // Например нажали на стрелку 2 языка
    $langTable=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM languages WHERE listOrder < $itemToUp LIMIT 1");
    while($oneLanguage=mysqli_fetch_assoc($langTable)){
      $getListOrder=$oneLanguage['listOrder'];// ( 1 )
      $sqlLangToUp=mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE languages SET listOrder=(@temp:=$itemToUp), listOrder = $getListOrder, listOrder = @temp WHERE listOrder < $itemToUp LIMIT 1 ");
    }
?>
```

[image: Пример таблицы языков]

Comment: а вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Как правильно записать этот запрос, чтобы поменять порядок языков

Comment: Написать **два** запроса. Обычных запроса по id.

Comment: Но мне нужно не по id, а с listOrder

Comment: Не нужно. Все операции со строками надо производить только по id. У поднимаемой строки увеличить listOrder на единицу, у опускаемой - уменьшить.

Comment: *Но мне нужно не по id, а с listOrder* Вот по исходному listOrder получите два id, а затем меняйте.

Comment: Все понял, спасибо